# Is there any way to unsubscribe child component's Subscriptions when element is removing from DOM using `renderer2.removeChild()` in angular?

Tags: html, angular

Rendering **HelloComponent** in **AppComponent** and when the element is removed from DOM by using `renderer.removeChild()`, `HelloComponent`'s  `ngOnDestroy` method is not firing. So unable to close the subscriptions of Hello Component.

Here is an example [stackbliz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zjyxfp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts)

Answer (score 0):

Wow, don't you want to destroy them with plain old *ngIf? It would make life so much easier. Anyway, you can use mutation observers.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

Roughly, and crudely, it could look like this:

```
  constructor(private ref: ElementRef) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    const ref = this.ref;

    this.subscription = this.myObservable.subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
    });

    const config = { childList: true };

    const cb = function(mutationList, observer) {
      for (const mutation of mutationList) {
        for (const node of mutation.removedNodes) {
          if(node === ref.nativeElement) {
            console.log("I've just been destroyed");
          }
        }
      }
    };

    const observer = new MutationObserver(cb);

    observer.observe(this.ref.nativeElement.parentNode, config);
  }
```

Stackblitz here:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wutq9j?file=src/app/hello.component.ts